# If unproven premises lead to a valid conclusion, could this be a coincidence?

Tags: premises

Suppose that one has a bunch of unproven premises, which lead to a valid conclusion. Instead of this proving that the premises are true, could it be a coincidence that the conclusion is true, not dependent on the truth of the premises?

Comment: You can prove 1+1=2 from the Continuum Hypothesis, so yes.

Comment: There are quite a few issues here. When you say 'valid conclusion' do you mean that the argument is valid, or the conclusion is a valid sentence? And why would you be trying to prove the premises are true? The point of a valid argument is to prove the conclusion is true, provided the premises are. If you are asking can a valid argument have premises that are irrelevant to the conclusion, then yes. At least in classical logic.

Comment: P1: If I am a wizard, the Sun rose this morning. P2: I am a wizard. C: The Sun rose this morning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do premises need to be true?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108357/do-premises-need-to-be-true)

Answer (score 0):

Premise 1: Socrates is a cat

Premise 2: all cats are greek philosophers

Conclusion: Socrates is a greek philosopher

Premise 1 and 2 are very unproven yet the conclusion is correct. So clearly, one can reach true conclusions with false premises.

Now, the exact probability that premises are wrong but coincidentally happen to lead to a true conclusion depends on each specific case, so it's difficult to give a general answer to your question, but it suffice to say that reasoning backward is unsound to warrant caution.

Actually, there is no shortage of example for people happening to be right for the wrong reason. It happens often that someone who makes a lot of poor predictions ends up being right once on a while. Political analysts and pundits are quite adept at this. Faith healers also come to mind.

Comment: Probability does not exist mind independently. There is no such thing as “the exact probability that premises are wrong”.

Comment: @Baby_philosopher so the probability that a a given atom of cesium 137 emit a beta particle depends on my thoughts about it?

Comment: There is no “probability” for a given atom decaying. **No one knows** when a given atom of cesium 137 will decay. All we know is that historically, we have observed **groups** of atoms decaying  at a constant rate. But we already have a term for that: it’s called historical frequency

Comment: What is the historical frequency of a premise being true?

Comment: @Baby_philosopher that you don't know the probability changes nothing to the probability itself. Also, "we don't know" is precisely my point so your objection is not only misguided but also irrelevant.

Comment: The dunning Kruger is strong on this one. I’m not asking you what the probability is. I’m asking you whether or not there is a true probability for a certain premise being true in the first place. Is there a probability figure for the statement “Flowers are red”?